# Every time I start my laptop proxy settings are automatically changed in the browser?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, proxy, lan

My browsers(chrome) proxy settings are updated after some time and then i'm not able to access internet. To access internet I have to manually change the LAN settings. I'm not able to find a solution to that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go into chrome://settings and change your proxy settings in there, and then click "apply" and "ok" to save the settings. If that doesn't work, keep your computer on sleep mode instead of turning it off and that will keep your settings intact